# Update opacity of a wpf ListBox item via binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a list box that looks like this:

```
<ListBox  
     ItemsSource="{Binding LoadingModules}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Opacity="{Binding ModuleLoaded, Mode=TwoWay, 
                               Converter={StaticResource BoolToDoubleConverter}}"
                     Text="{Binding ModuleName}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The idea is that any item with ModuleLoaded = true should have 20 percent opacity.

This works great at design time.  But at run time this does not happen.

This is my logic where I actually change the value:

```
private void OnModuleLoaded(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
{
    LoadingModules.Where(x => x.ModuleName == moduleInfo.ModuleName)
                  .FirstOrDefault().ModuleLoaded = true;
}
```

Any my LoadingModule class has ModuleLoaded defined like this:

```
private bool moduleLoaded;
public bool ModuleLoaded 
{
    get { return moduleLoaded ; }
    set
    {
        if (!object.Equals(moduleLoaded , value))
        {
            moduleLoaded  = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModuleLoaded ");
        }
    }
}
```

The only way I have been able to get it to work is by doing this:

```
var foundModule = LoadingModules.Where(x => x.ModuleName==moduleInfo.ModuleName)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
LoadingModules.Remove(foundModule);
foundModule.ModuleLoaded = false;
LoadingModules.Add(foundModule);
```

This does work, so I know that my bindings and converter are wired up.

But removing and re-adding is not really a solution.  And it causes problems because my events don't arrive in perfect order.

**Is there any way I can get my ListBox.ItemTemplate DataTemplate to update on the fly based on a binding?**

Comment: Please post BoolToDoubleConverter and verify it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `"ModuleLoaded "` instead of `"ModuleLoaded"` to your `OnPropertyChanged` call. This means that even though your property value changes, the UI does not get informed about it and thus retains its original state.

Other than that, your `Where` call is redundant. Instead of calling

```
LoadingModules.Where(x => x.ModuleName == moduleInfo.ModuleName)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

you can simply call

```
LoadingModules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ModuleName == moduleInfo.ModuleName);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!   I checked the spelling on that string 3 separate times!  But I was only looking for spelling.  (I may have been a bit too focused :)  Thanks for tip on the FirstOrDefault too.